# How to share globals in Python threads and functions

Tags: python, multithreading, global-variables

I have two files for a simple program, MyConfig.py:

```
class MyConfig(object):
        a = False
        b = 0
```

And mytest.py:

```
import sys

# Globals
sys.path.append('.')
from MyConfig import MyConfig

def test():
        MyConfig.a = False
        MyConfig.b = 32
        print("MyConfig.a = {}".format(MyConfig.a))
        print("MyConfig.b = {}".format(MyConfig.b))

if __name__ == '__main__':

        if len(sys.argv) == 2:
                MyConfig.a = True
                MyConfig.b = int(sys.argv[1])

        print("MyConfig.a = {}".format(MyConfig.a))
        print("MyConfig.b = {}".format(MyConfig.b))

        test()
```

Output:

```
MyConfig.a = True
MyConfig.b = 3
MyConfig.a = False
MyConfig.b = 32
```

This seems like a convoluted way to share some config info, but I can't seem to do the same thing in a multithreaded Python app.  In this app, the MyConfig.x MyConfig.y and MyConfig.z are assigned at start up.

If I do the same thing, in threadapp.py:

```
import sys

# Globals
sys.path.append('.')
from MyConfig import MyConfig

# Some functions used by the app
...

def data_export(queue):
   ...

def worker(queue):
   ...

def process(data, foo):
   ...

def thread(iterator):
   processes = []
   data = Queue()
   data_factory = Process(target = data_export, args = (data,))
   data_factory.daemon = True
   processes.append(data_factory)
   data_factory.start()
   work = Process(target = worker, args = (data,))
   work.daemon = True
   processes.append(work)
   work.start()
   data_factory.join()

def main():

    cfg = MyConfig()

    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        cfg.a = True
        cfg.b = int(sys.argv[1])

    print ("cfg.a = {}".format(cfg.a))
    print ("cfg.b = {}".format(cfg.b))

    try:
        pool = ThreadPool(processes = multiprocessing.cpu_count()*2)
        pool.map(thread, range(0, 10))
    except:
        pool.close()
        exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My problem is that I can't access the global MyConfig (cfg) anywhere in the functions the threads use.  I can see when I start the program that the variables are set in cfg., in main(), but when I try to access them in functions the threads use, they are all set to their default values, and I can't set them and read them back.

I've been searching on this for hours with no luck, only simple globals where I would declare 'global foo' in a function that wanted to read or modify a global variable.  I can't seem to do that here.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To declare a global  thread2,

```
def thread2(threadname):
    global a
    while True:
        a += 1
        time.sleep(1)
```

In thread1, you don't need to do anything special, as long as you don't try to modify the value of a (which would create a local variable that shadows the global one; use global a if you need to)>

```
def thread1(threadname):
    #global a       # Optional if you treat a as read-only
    while a < 10:
        print a
```